# Adding multiple lines to a UILabel that is updated by a UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel

So i'm making an application where the user converts the data from a UITextField into a UILabel. However, when updating a large amount of text instead of overflowing into another line, it simply displays '...' when there are too many words. I've tried changing the number of lines in the UILabel, even changing it to '0' which should mean the text displayed should fit the words in the UITextField, but this isn't the case. The following code I have for the UITextField to the UILabel is:

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
NSString *input = text1.text;
label1.text = input;
NSString *Input = text2.text;
label2.text = Input;
```

I'm new to developing and I've checked documentation and have found nothing. I did notice someone saying I should use a UITextField, however this doesn't suit my needs as to what i require the UILabel to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try setting the **lineBreakMode** property of the **UILabel** to ***NSLineBreakByWordWrapping***, as the default value for this property is actually ***NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail*** which could explain the *'...'* that you're experiencing when the label has too much text. Also make sure the **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** property is set to **NO**.

```
textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO; // this is default value
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: ahhh yes it was the lineBreakMode that had me done
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Options for UITextView that you may have not seen

```
 UITextView * _descriptionText = [UITextView new];

[_descriptionText setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[[_descriptionText textContainer] setMaximumNumberOfLines:11];
[[_descriptionText textContainer] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```

Not sure if this helps, but combining this with Bamsworlds answer should do it